# v2 Function Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.QueueTriggerAttribute'

Tags: azure-functions

V2 App that used to work. When I try to run it now I get the following error:

`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'MyClass.Run'. System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.QueueTriggerAttribute' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.`

---

May also show for `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.BlobTriggerAttribute`, `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.BlobAttribute`, `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.TableAttribute`, or `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.QueueAttribute`

Answer (score 23):

There was a recent release of Azure Functions v2 preview [detailed here](http://aka.ms/func2di) which requires triggers and bindings that depend on storage to pull in an additional Azure Storage extension.  The templates should reflect this change automatically.

To pull in yourself, get the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage`  Nuget Package.

For non-C# apps, running `func extensions install` should pull in the right storage extension.

Comment: Wow ... that solved it for me after a few hours of searching around. Thx! Mark is as the correct answer please :-)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me too, but I also had to install the `Newtonsoft.Json` package (v12.0.2 at the time of this post) first before I could install the Storage package.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: Switching `Platform` from `32 Bit` to `64 Bit` fixed this issue for me.[image]